# Extracting script of tool in ArcGIS? and combining the tools join by attribute and join based spatial location?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcpy

my subject is to match between two data bases related to cartography details and second toponomy. 
I have ArcGIS 10.0 and I want to combine the tool of join by attribute and based by spatial location. 
that why I want to inspire from the already scripts that ArcGIS use.

Comment: Are you using arcpy? What is it that you're trying to do, a spatial join and an attribute join then save those results to a new shapefile?

Comment: I think we need much more detail.  My interpretation from your title was that you appear to be wanting to get below the system tools level so you might be looking for ArcObjects or C++ code.

Comment: All the sub-system code for ArcGis is proprietary and protected by copyright. If you want to see how it's done on the most basic level get the source code for QGIS which implements attribute and spatial joins. You can however use the spatial join and attribute joins in arcpy to perform your tasks - see answer by artwork21.

Comment: @Michael yes, I want to use arcpy. I am trying to use both join by attribute and join based spatial but I find a difficulty. I don't know how to get it.

Comment: Please use the **edit** button beneath your question to revise it with these additional details.

Comment: I'm still not at all clear about what you are asking.  Are you perhaps under the misapprehension that there is ArcPy code behind Attribute and Spatial Joins?

Answer (score 2):

Most of the geoprocessing tools have a python method (using arcpy module) that will allow you run them via a custom script.  See links below for more details.

[Understanding tool syntax](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Understanding_tool_syntax/002t00000011000000/)

[Join Field (Data Management)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000065000000)

[Spatial Join (Analysis)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000q000000)